# Changing permissions for specific folder

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, fedora, chmod

i need some help. I'm using Fedora 15. I have 2 users: user1 and user2 and directory in /usr/local/example_directory. Now for this directory owner is user1 and other users can only read this. I need to add specific permissions for user2 so it can remove and modify this directory recursively. How i can do it?
P.S.: Sorry for bad language.

Comment: The keyword is "group".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could go 2 ways:

1. via ACLs, where you can have several users with special permissions: see `man setfacl`.
2. via a special group: Put all files into a group `example_admins`, make them group-writable and add `user1` and `user2` into that group.

Answer (score 0):

```
chown -R user2 /usr/local/example_directory
```

Comment: Then `user1` loses his permissions. Not what is wanted, I think.

Comment: Oh, would you mind to put user1 & user2 into same group?
Then you can do chmod g+w -R /usr/local/example_directory

Comment: That could be one way to go...

Comment: The best I can figured out, sorry for my silly answer.